# How can I determine all loops in the list below (schedule). I need for a VBA code to determine these loops (list will be dynamic)

Tags: loops, linked-list

[**Loops in the Task Relationships**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5do9.png)
This image shows an example from a schedule in Primavera. All links are based on the successors.